# Python-- Print result shows "None" and the desired result

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that should be printing a number. But it instead prints "None", along with the number I anticipated it to print. Here is the snippet of code that should produce, at the very last line, just the number 3.

```
mylist=[]
def number_replied(user):
    for z in task1dict:
        if user in task1dict[z]:
            mylist.append(z) 

def how_many_replied_to(username):
    del(mylist[:])
    number_replied(username)
    print(len(mylist))

print(how_many_replied_to('joeclarkphd'))
```

This should produce the result, "3", but it shows "None", a line break, "3". Is there something I need to add or change? Let me know if you need more of the code.

Comment: change the print(len(mylist)) to `return len(mylist)`  Your function currently returns None by default since you don't have a return statement

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404947/my-function-returns-none

Answer (score 0):

Functions return `None` unless they have a `return something_that_is_not_none` statement that gets executed in the function's body.

You are printing the value in the function, returning `None` and then printing that return value in the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the previous answer, change the last line of the second function from `print(len(mylist))` to `return len(mylist)` and you're good to go.